# How to add decimal values in linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I have seven decimal fields in my table. I want all values sum.

If I am adding normally like  `val =  (i.val1 + i.val2 + ... i.val7)` I am getting the value only if all fields are not null, if any of these fields are the value is displaying as null.

Can you tell me how to do this?

```
var query = dbContext.weekly_details
    .Select(i => new
    {
        total_Prj_project_time_entry_day = i.time_entry_day_1 +
            i.time_entry_day_2 +
            i.time_entry_day_3 +
            i.time_entry_day_4 +
            i.time_entry_day_5 +
            i.time_entry_day_6 +
            i.time_entry_day_7
    })
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Can you show the actual code you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
val = (new decimal?[]{i.val1, i.val2, i.val3, i.val4, i.val5, i.val6, i.val7}).Sum()
```

Full code

```
 var query = dbContext.weekly_details.Select
                  (i => (new decimal?[]{
    i.time_entry_day_1,                                                                  
    i.time_entry_day_2,                                                                               
    i.time_entry_day_3,
    i.time_entry_day_4,                                                                               
    i.time_entry_day_5,                                                                               
    i.time_entry_day_6,
    i.time_entry_day_7}).Sum()).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Linq;

var i = new List<int?>
{
    1,
    null,
    3
}

var total = i.Sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could probably do

```
var query = dbContext.weekly_details
    .Select(i => new
    {
        total_Prj_project_time_entry_day = 
            i.time_entry_day_1 ?? 0 +
            i.time_entry_day_2 ?? 0 +
            i.time_entry_day_3 ?? 0 +
            i.time_entry_day_4 ?? 0 +
            i.time_entry_day_5 ?? 0 +
            i.time_entry_day_6 ?? 0 +
            i.time_entry_day_7 ?? 0
    })
    .ToArray();
```

so it will add 0 to the total if the value of any of the `time_entry_day_n` are `null`.